# Map with clickable polygons to extract properties and fill a table column using HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, dictionary, mapbox, geocoding

I'm not experienced in coding... I created an interactive map from mapbox with a vector file from a tileset. In adition to that i added a slidebar in the left side of the map and inside of the slidebar a table. With a POPOUT when i click a "CROP FIELD"...

lIKE THIS:

```html
<html>
 <head>
     <meta charset='utf-8' />
     <title>Locator</title>
     <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
     <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.52.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
     <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.52.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
   </head>

     <style>
   body {
    color:#404040;
    font:400 15px/22px 'Source Sans Pro', 'Helvetica Neue', Sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;
   }

   .sidebar {
    position:absolute;
    width:20.0%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;left:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
   }

   .map {
    position:absolute;
    left:20.0%;
    width:80.0%;
    top:0;bottom:0;
   }
             table.minimalistBlack {
          margin:0px 0px;
                 border: 2px solid #000000;
                 width: 20%;
                 text-align: left;
                 border-collapse: collapse;
          

               }
               table.minimalistBlack td, table.minimalistBlack th {
                 border: 1px solid #000000;
                 padding: 5px 4px;
               }
               table.minimalistBlack tbody td {
                 font-size: 13px;
               }
               table.minimalistBlack thead {
                 background: #009933;
                 border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
               }
               table.minimalistBlack thead th {
                 font-size: 15px;
                 font-weight: bold;
                 color: #ffffff;
                 text-align: left;
                 border-left: 2px solid #009933;
               }
               table.minimalistBlack thead th:first-child {
                 border-left: none;
               }

               table.minimalistBlack tfoot td {
                 font-size: 14px;
               }


     </style>
 <body>

    <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div id='map' class='map'></div>
  <table  style="width:20%">
   <tr>
        <table class="minimalistBlack">
        <thead><tr>
        <th>CARACTERISTICAS</th>
        <th></th>
        </tr></thead>
        <tbody><tr>
        <td>LLAVE</td>
        <td id='f1'>cell2_1</td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>NOMBRE DE PLANTA</td>
        <td id='f2'>cell2_2</td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>COLONIA</td>
        <td id='f3'>cell2_3</td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>VARIEDAD</td>
        <td id='f4'>cell2_4</td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>ZAFRA</td>
        <td id='f5'>cell2_5</td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>HA-REAL</td>
        <td id='f6'>cell2_6</td>
        </tr> <tr>
        <td>TCH-REAL</td>
        <td id='f7'>cell2_7</td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>HA-COLONIA</td>
        <td id='f8'>cell2_8</td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>TCH-COLONIA</td>
        <td id='f9'>cell2_9</td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>EDAD DEL CULTIVO</td>
        <td id='f10'>cell2_10</td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>NUMERO DE CORTES</td>
        <td id='f11'>cell2_11</td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>TIPO DE CORTES</td>
        <td id='f12'>cell2_12</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <a href="#"></a></td>
        </tr><tr>
        </table></div>
   <script>
   mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZXhhbXBsZXMiLCJhIjoiY2lqbmpqazdlMDBsdnRva284cWd3bm11byJ9.V6Hg2oYJwMAxeoR9GEzkAA';
   var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v9',
      center: [-69.509284, 18.587161],
      zoom: 12.80,
    });

    map.on('load', function () {
     map.addSource('testile', {
            type: 'vector',
            url: 'mapbox://leanamatos.cjqpet0n307lp30nagf56xi89-5tui0'
            });

      map.addLayer({
        'id': 'campos',
        'type': 'fill',
        'source': 'testile',
        'source-layer': 'testile',
        'layout': { },
        'paint': {
          'fill-color': 'transparent',
          'fill-outline-color': '#000000',
          'fill-opacity': 1
            }
        });

        // When a click event occurs on a feature in the states layer, open a popup at the
         // location of the click, with description HTML from its properties.
         map.on('click', 'campos', function (e) {
      var description = e.features[0].properties.LLAVE;
          var description2 = e.features[0].properties.AREA_HA;
          var description3 = e.features[0].properties.Cosechado;
               new mapboxgl.Popup()
                   .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
                   .setHTML("LLAVE" + ": "+ description + "<br/>"
                   +"AREA" + ": "+ description2+"ha" + "<br/>"
                   +"ZAFRA" + ": "+ description3)
   
                   .addTo(map);
           });
         // Change the cursor to a pointer when the mouse is over the states layer.
         map.on('mouseenter', 'campos', function () {
             map.getCanvas().style.cursor = 'pointer';
         });

         // Change it back to a pointer when it leaves.
         map.on('mouseleave', 'campos', function () {
             map.getCanvas().style.cursor = '';
         });
});

  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to create a event where users can click on the CROP FIELDS from the tilset and then inside the table column shows the corresponding polygon's properties (LIKE THE INFO INSIDE THE POPOUTS) but insted of that inside the columns from the table. Right know I'm just geting errors...

I tried this coding, but I really dont know if I should go this way:

```
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.on('click', function (e) {

onMapClick(coords);
//place attributes in panel table.
var field1=e.features[0].properties.LLAVE; ('f1');
field1.innerHTML=e.target.feature.properties.League;
var field2=e.features[0].properties.NOMBRE DE PLANTA;('f2');
field2.innerHTML=e.target.feature.properties.Team;
var field3=e.features[0].properties.COLONIA;('f3');
field3.innerHTML=e.target.feature.properties.Address;
var field4=e.features[0].properties.VARIEDAD;('f4');
field4.innerHTML=e.target.feature.properties.Stadium;
var field5=e.features[0].properties.ZAFRA;('f5');
field5.innerHTML=e.target.feature.properties.Capacity;
var field6=e.features[0].properties.HA-REAL;('f6');
field6.innerHTML=e.target.feature.properties.Capacity;
var field7=e.features[0].properties.TCH-REAL;('f7');
field6.innerHTML=e.target.feature.properties.Capacity;
var field8=e.features[0].properties.HA-COLONIA;('f8');
field6.innerHTML=e.target.feature.properties.Capacity;
var field9=e.features[0].properties.TCH-COLONIA;('f9');
field6.innerHTML=e.target.feature.properties.Capacity;
var field10=e.features[0].properties.EDAD DEL CULTIVO;('f10');
field6.innerHTML=e.target.feature.properties.Capacity;
var field11=e.features[0].properties.NUMERO DE CORTES;('f11');
field6.innerHTML=e.target.feature.properties.Capacity;
var field12=e.features[0].properties.TIPO DE CORTES;('f12');
field6.innerHTML=e.target.feature.properties.Capacity;
```

});

If anyone could provide me some guidance on the best way to do this I'd really appreciate it.

I'm no coding expert so I might need some in-dept explanation. Thanks!!!!!